# Return control from controller's action with lambda in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, return, dry, proc

How can I fix this error? I want to DRY my controller, and in each method I perform a sanity check on params[], just making sure all params are present.

The problem is with lambda's return. As it is defined

```
def validate_input(parameters)
    return proc {
        if parameters.find_index { |i| i.nil? }
          error_message = {'Error' => 'Please fix some params'}.to_json
          render :json => error_message and return
        end
    }
  end
```

Then, inside my controller action I do:

```
def action
  ...
  validate_input([my_sane_id, my_other_param]).call
  ...
end
```

And get the error: unexpected return.

Comment: Do you get an indication of which line the unexpected return is on? My gut feel is you might not need it here: `render :json => error_message and return` due to implicit return.

Comment: But that's exactly what I want to do: after the validation, just return from the calling method. Mmm. After thinking a bit :) I see what you're saying. Will check that soon.

Comment: I just thought that seeing that you'd used `proc` - I know that in some versions of Ruby `proc` and `lambda` are interchangeable, but `Proc` and `Lambda` behave differently on return. http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby I think is the article I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def validate_input(*parameters)
  if parameters.any?(&:nil?)
     render :json => { :error => 'Please fix some params' }
     false
  else
     true
  end
end


def action
  ...
  return unless validate_input(my_sane_id, my_other_param)
  ...
end
```

1. you can use the splat operator ("*") to get unknown number of parameters into array
2. you can use ("any?") method instead of index (which is location)
3. you can use symbol to proc ("&:") if you only making the function call on each item in array
4. you dont need to call to_json if you render json
5. better use symbol as hash key (":error")
6. you return true/false to indicate if everything ok, and if its false, just return from the action

Comment: thanks but anyway i'd love to know how to use it with proc since that's the language's feature.